# Custom sound not working in firebase push notification when application closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

Custom sound not working in firebase push notification when application closed.

Code:

```
Uri norificationSoundURI = Uri.parse(ContrntResOlver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+”://“+ context.grtPackageName()+”/“+ R.raw.FILE_NAME);`
```

Comment: what is an error show in your logcat?

Comment: @BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri : Actually custom sound is working fine when application is open but same not working when application closed from background. So there is no any kind of error

Comment: notification.sound =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.FILE_NAME);//Here is FILE_NAME is the name of file that you want to play

Comment: Sorry @BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri not working above code when application is closed from background, only working when application is open

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem some time ago, and my solution was removing "context.getPackageName()" - just hardcode your package name.

So try:

```
Uri norificationSoundURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://COM.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.BLA/"+R.raw.FILE_NAME);
```